# Expose fuse mounted inside a docker container

Tags: docker, fuse

I'm trying to run a docker image for mounting hubic (online storage) and expose that to the host

What is working so far is container mounting the fuse point correctly (to `/mnt/hubic`)

When running docker I am attempting to run with volume mapped as `/path/on/host:/mnt/hubic` this appears to work ( ie docker makes the directory if it doesn't exist) but the contents never appear. If I enter the container I can see the files from the online storage but the host folder contains nothing

Is there an option I'm missing to allow docker to do this ?

Command I am using to start the container

`docker run -v ~/.hubicfuse:/root/.hubicfuse -v /tmp/mounted:/mnt/hubic --device /dev/fuse --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --security-opt apparmor:unconfined -it {container_name}`

Comment: @kamil I wish to read the files from the host. Using a shared volume. Normally inside a container you can mount a directory from inside to be a real directory on the host. Hoping this is also possible with fuse

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43687970/165358) on using the `:shared` flag, which might also work for FUSE.

Comment: @harrymc that worked ! can you make it an answer ?

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution comes from the post
[s3 mounted inside the container. how to expose it to the host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687025/s3-mounted-inside-the-container-how-to-expose-it-to-the-host)

In this post is described a solution using `glusterFS`, requiring more
permissions for the container. The docker command used:

```
docker run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --device fuse -v host_mount_dir:container_mount_dir:shared IMAGE COMMAND
```

For an error like
"Path /foo is mounted on /foo but it is not a shared mount ...",
the reason is that the docker daemon runs in different mount namespace than
systemd. This is the solution for making it run in the same namespace:

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/
cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/clear_mount_propagation_flags.conf
[Service]
MountFlags=shared
EOF
```

And restart the docker daemon.

A remark is that the mount is visible on the host if mounted into a directory
binded by `-v`.